# git keeps complaining about non existing master on remote...?

Tags: linux, git, github, upstream-branch

When I try to fo a `git pull`, I get:

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

when I'm on `master`. I have tried:

- `git reset --soft HEAD`
- `git branch --unset-upstream` & `git pull --set-upstream-to=origin/correct-branch-name` (as well as with: `git pull --set-upstream origin master`

but nothing seems to work, the remote is small, there's only three branches on this trepository.... can anyone give me a hand with this?

**UPDATE1**

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/added_RGB_led
  origin/button_features
  origin/master
]$ git fetch --prune origin
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I do have the correct permissions setup, this is new...

```
$ git ls-remote origin
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I tried to do fresh clone and got the following:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:organisation/Repo.git
Cloning into 'Repo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 193, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (193/193), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (107/107), done.
remote: Total 193 (delta 62), reused 175 (delta 45), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (193/193), 41.66 KiB | 804.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (62/62), done.
fatal: bad object refs/heads/master
fatal: remote did not send all necessary objects
$ cd Repo/
$ git status
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home/user)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

I'm really not sure what's going on, this all looks very odd to me

Comment: What branches show up in the remote if you run `git branch -r`? Sounds like either the branch does not exist (maybe it's called `main` instead? Or it was deleted? `git fetch --prune origin` could tell you if that was the case) or the remote is empty so no branch there yet.

Comment: Which branches exist on the remote? `git reset` only affects your local branches. What does `git ls-remote origin` output?

Comment: @eftshift0 please see above **UPDATE1**

Comment: @knittlplease see above **UPDATE1**

Answer (score 1):

It is a very strange issue.

I can only suggest you to do what `git pull` does behind the scenes:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```